# On definition of a surface-knot

Tags: knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, knot-invariants

A surface-knot is a closed surface embedded in 4-dimensianal space. Some authors define this embedding as a smooth embedding while others define it locally flatly. I don't know whether or not there is a difference between these two definitions?

Comment: @MoisheCohen I know that's open in the case of genus $0$ and I think it's open in the  case of genus $1$. Where do you get a higher genus example?

Comment: @PVAL-inactive: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Two references:

1. [Wild branching surfaces and topological 4-manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07459)  by Piergallini and Zuddas (arXiv:1602.07459v1).

From this you conclude that there are tame closed surfaces in $S^4$ not isotopic to smooth ones (take a branched cover of a nonsmoothable 4-manifold over $S^4$). I am sure it was known earlier.

2. [Exotic knottings of surfaces in the 4-sphere](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1987-17-02/S0273-0979-1987-15562-5/home.html) by Finashin, Kreck and Viro.

From this you conclude that there are smooth surfaces in $S^4$ which are topologically but not smoothly isotopic.